# How to know the first R version to have a given function

Tags: r

Just today, I tried to launch through `Rscript` a code on an old server. My script received an unexpected error:

```
Error: could not find function `paste0`
```

It turned out that the R version installed on the server was an old one (2.14). The `paste0` came with later R versions. In the help page of `paste0` (or in any other R function as far as I know) the first version supporting it is not mentioned.

My question: is there a way to know the version in which a given function has been introduced? Something like the `Since:` section in the java documentation. Thanks.

Edit:

I can maybe formulate my question better. There is a reason why this information is not provided directly in the help page? If so, which is it? If not, should next R releases provide it?

Comment: Myabe you could scarp [this page](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/NEWS.R-3.1.2.html) and [this](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/NEWS.2.html), etc.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, I knew that way... but I hoped for something quicker.

Comment: Sure, I could. But it happens that sometimes I need to develop some code without knowing in advance on which server it will run. And often you cannot update the server. In general, it seems that I don't have an easy way to know if my code is 2.13 compatible, 2.14 compatible and so. The only way seems to try and see.

Comment: https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/42afe14553a03f0266d0284cd02a1242dd9d506c

Comment: @Roland Thank you for your comment. I was searching for something more general that could allow you to know whether your code is backward compatible with some R version. Sure, in some way you can know with a little research the version of a function. But why is it not mentioned? Is it an issue that should be brought to the attention of the R core team? Next R releases should provide this information? And if not, why?

Comment: I agree that this would be nice to have in the documentation, but it would probably be a lot of work at this stage to add it. Nowadays there are not that many functions added to R-base. It might be simpler for your purpose to extract a list of added functions from the NEWS files for recent (or not so recent in your case) versions.

Comment: @Roland I agree with you. But maybe something in the middle should be feasible. For instance, by starting from functions introduced from R 3.0.0 (they are not that many) and keeping the habit.

Comment: Closed - I asked this same question.  Not surprisingly (although not mentioned in the question) paste0 was one of the functions I was interested in.

Comment: I'm now noticing your extra questions that you edited in.  I'm still going to say that this is a duplicate since those questions aren't really SO material since the answer kind of is "because that's the way it is" - if you want to request it go to the mailing lists.

Comment: @Dason No problem at all. I didn't notice your question and if I did, I wouldn't have asked. I agree that it is a duplicated.